# Updated laptop from 16.10 to 18.04 LTS, Stuck at /dev/... clean, ***/*** files, ***/*** blocks

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, 16.10, fsck

Haven't touched this laptop in a while, so when I did, I updated it to the most recent LTS.

It is a dual-booting Windows 10/Ubuntu system.

I get stuck at 
`/dev/nvme0n1p7: clean, 291381/1324512 files, 3883511/5297920 blocks.`
after selecting Ubuntu in GRUB.

I saw some other users fix by purging nvidia drivers, which my system does not have (no nvidia GPU, tried it anyway, just listed 0 installed, 0 removed etc.)

Saw some others suggest `sudo apt update`, to which I got these:

`Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease   Could not resolve 'au.archive.ubuntu.com'` and similar 5 other lines, with the last one being `cannot resolve 'dl.google.com'`.

Does anyone know what I can do to get back into my system?

Comment: If you can do `sudo apt update` you can get into your system somehow. Do you mean you can boot in recovery mode? You don't appear to have a valid network connection to the laptop, at least no valid DNS settings.

Comment: @Jos is correct. I also don't recommend upgrading LTS versions. It's better to wipe out the old and install the new. You should be able to get access to your files by choosing "Advanced Options for Ubuntu", mount the disk with /home and copy to where ever you like (easiest way is to a usb: "mkdir /tmp/usb" then "mount /dev/sd??" (check fdisk -l to get device name) and copy your files to the usb. At this point you can run the install from an ISO and as a bonus you get to setup your system all over again :P.  If you haven't touched the laptop in a while, why not wipe out Windows also?

Comment: @JaradDowning upgrading LTS versions is a tested, supported upgrade path that we help troubleshoot here. Many folks like to upgrade, many others like to clean-install. Let's let the OP grow their own opinion on the topic.

Comment: I get a terminal interface when I get stuck in booting by using ctrl alt f2, not sure what I can do from here on, though.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem with a system that had an AMD gpu and have seen recommendations from people using Intel's integrated GPUs to remove drivers.

So I booted up into recovery mode and removed AMDs GPU drivers and voila it worked.

Comment: OP asked how to get back into his system and I tried to give me a possible solution. Note that Ive installed the lasted drivers twice from AMD and ended up getting stuck with same message again. Removing the drivers got me back into my system. I dont know exactly whats causing it though.